# Handle a file attachment rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form in my rails app where a user is supposed to attach a csv file. The form works and allows for a successful upload, but what happens to that file from there? I am trying to better understand this as I need to use the file. This is essentiall how I have it:

```
 <%= bootstrap_form_for(@migration) do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.file_field :csv, label: "CSV File", class: 'form-control'%>
    ...
 <% end %>
```

How do I access this file now? Calling `@migration.csv` just returns a reference. Is there a path that it saves to? Or am I missing a step altogether? I am new to rails so I am trying to better understand how this works. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached file should be in `params[:migrations][:csv]`. [See the guides notes on the `file_field` helper.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)